# VHDL ERROR : Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net... : for loop

Tags: vhdl

I have a little problem with this vhdl code, it says that:

> Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net
>   "leds[25]" at pong_game.vhd(1049) ...

Here is a part of my code :

```
architecture led_matrix of pong_game is 

...

type etat is 
(led1,led2,led3,led4,led5,led6_1,led7_1_g,led7_1_d,led8_1_g,led8_1_d,led9_1_g 
...)

signal etat_present, etat_futur : etat;

...

affichage_sequence : process(etat_present)
begin
case etat_present is
when led1 =>
    for i in 1 to 30 loop
        if i = 1 then
            leds(i)<='1';
        else
            leds(i)<='0';
        end if;
    end loop;
when led2 =>
    for i in 1 to 30 loop
        if i = 2 then
            leds(i)<='1';
        else
            leds(i)<='0';
        end if;
    end loop;
when led3
...

end case ;

end process affichage_sequence ;

end architecture led_matrix;
```

Is there a better way to perform these operations?

Comment: This error appears because the signal (or port) `leds` is driven in more than one process. We need to see more than only this process to help you resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it could be really simple, but what is happening with your states?

```
[...]led5,led6_1,led7_1_g,led7_1_d[...]
```

All kind of weird names. What are you trying to achieve?

As for the process:

```
begin
    case etat_present is
        when led1 =>
            leds <= (1 <= '1', others => '0');
        when led2 =>
            leds <= (2 <= '1', others => '0');
    [...]
```

or

```
begin
    case etat_present is
        when led1 =>
            leds <= (others => '0'); leds(1) <= '1';
        when led2 =>
            leds <= (others => '0'); leds(2) <= '1';
    [...]
```

or

```
begin
    leds <= (others => '0');
    case etat_present is
        when led1 =>
            leds(1) <= '1';
        when led2 =>
            leds(2) <= '1';
    [...]
```

Depending on your requirements and the support of the synthesis tool.

But we're missing the code to see why `leds(25)` has multiple drivers. So can't help you there.

What did simulation say? I *hope* you simulated this. Straight to FPGA is usually a bad idea.

Change the `leds` signal type to `std_ulogic_vector` and test in simulation, which will give an earlier error.

Comment: Without seeing all the assignments to leds in all the states in the shown process snippet you can't determine setting all the leds to '0's in other states is appropriate. It's safer to use an aggregate expression, e.g. `when led1 => leds(1 => '1', others => '0');` or  two assignments in each state e.g. `leds. <= (others => '0'); leds(1) <= '1';`

Comment: @user1155120 I chose the two expression variant, because I remember the synthesis tools having issues with aggregate expressions in the past. But maybe they fixed that in the mean time.

Comment: Array aggregates (expressions) have been required to be supported for compliant synthesis since IEEE Std 1076.6-1999 Register Transfer Level (RTL) Synthesis (8.7.3.2 Aggregates). Are you referring to record aggregates? (Not supported in -1999, supported in -2004).

Comment: @user1155120 well, that's good news. I remember getting some errors in the past, and have been using the two-assignment method since then. Never tested if it was 'fixed' since.

Comment: Supporting record element names required a new synthesis construct that has been since used in other HDLs.

Answer (score -2):

You are assigning a value to led(i) in different places ( in multiple possibility of your case) that is the problem. You should assign a variable. And depending on the value of the variable assign a value to led(i).